Optimise count(*) query for pagination
What is the best approach to do pagination ,if I dont want to use select count(*) to get the total number of records at the same time i want to show page no.
also how to optimise count(*) queries
I'm using erlang's epgsql to execute the queries
I bought data using keyset method and sub query both are pretty fast ...Im facing issue in bringing total number of records as it takes some time ...

A count(*) query to calculate the total result set count is always expensive: it has to compute the complete result set and count the rows. There is very little you can do to optimize such queries.
The road to happiness is not to compute the exact result set count. There are two good approaches:

Get an estimate using EXPLAIN, for example with a function like
CREATE FUNCTION row_estimate(text) RETURNS bigint
   LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$$DECLARE
   j jsonb;
BEGIN
   EXECUTE 'EXPLAIN (FORMAT JSON) ' || $1 INTO j;
   RETURN (j[0]['Plan']['Plan Rows'])::bigint;
END;$$;

Such a function can be abused with SQL injection, so don't use it with SQL statements from untrusted sources.

Don't display the result set count at all, but instead provide a button “calculate the exact result set count”. In those 99% of the cases where the users don't need the result set count, they just don't use the button. If they really need the count, they will have to wait while the expensive query is executing.


See also this and this article for detailed information.
